# SharePoint Calendar Validation - Time Limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, validation, column-validation

=AND(AND(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY([Start Time]),FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),IF(OR(TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="12:30",TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="13:15",TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="13:30"),TRUE,FALSE)),IF(AND(DATEDIF([Start Time],[End Time],"d")=0,TEXT([End Time]-[Start Time],"h:mm")="0:15"),TRUE,FALSE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the condition to this formula:

([End Time] is the same day as [Start Time] and allowed limit is 0 hour 15 minutes)

```
=AND(AND(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY([Start Time]),FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),IF(OR(TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="12:30",TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="13:15",TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm")="13:30"),TRUE,FALSE)),IF(AND(DATEDIF([Start Time],[End Time],"d")=0,TEXT([End Time]-[Start Time],"h:mm")="0:15"),TRUE,FALSE))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!